# How can I speed drying of oil primer on a garage cabinet?

Tags: primer, spraypainting, refinishing

Here’s my setup. First time using a paint sprayer and will be using oil based primer Zinsser Cover Stain, which smells badly:

[image]

Is this overkill for cabinet refinishing with a sprayer?

So far I’ve been using a small fan and opening the garage half way and opening then sides for ventilation in the daytime. During the day, it’s about 70F and at night time it gets down to 50s (I keep the small fan on). I life in LA so humidity is low.

What should I do differently to help speed up the dry time for my primer/paints?

Comment: Spray thinner coats, same comment here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/210460/97780

Answer (score 1):

> Is this overkill for cabinet refinishing with a sprayer?

This is a matter of opinion; in my opinion yes that is overkill. Plus, you have created a humidity-trapping box. Think about professional spray booths; they are equipped with powerful ventilation systems.

The product guide says to apply "only when air, material, and surface temperatures are between 40-80°F and the relative humidity
should not be greater than 85%". Right now in my part of LA it is 40°F and 76% relative humidity. It is likely that as air temp rises, the material you are painting will take longer to warm up.

I think you can improve dry time by increasing air circulation and temperature.

Comment: Why would high humidity increase the drying time of an oil based primer or paint? There are two distinct processes at work--the evaporation of the volatile carrier solvent, followed by curing of what remains.  Following priming with oil based primer, how long before applying paint? Can the primer be tacky or must it be cured hard?

Comment: @Jim Stewart, the manufacturer specifically states that high humidity will increase both the dry and cure time. It seems counter-intuitive in reference to solvent based products, but if I reach into the deep recesses of my memory of physics and chemistry lessons, I think about *partial pressure* and stuff... I don't really know but someone on the Physics stack exchange could probably explain...